# What is best coding practices for providing an upgrade path to a new module version?

Tags: 7, updating

I'm getting ready to build a new version of a module of mine. The new version can have an upgrade path from the current version to the new version that will be released, but as you know, new major verions come with database restructuring, entity refactoring, and what not.

Is there a standard practice in the way the upgrade path is provided? For instance, should I build code in the install hook of the new version, and update hook, or some stand alone script?

Suggestions welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

Add the install information required for the new module version in the [hook_install](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_install/7) and [hook_schema](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7).

Users upgrading presumably won't be re-installing the module, so you'll need to use [hook_update_N](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7) for those users. Check if the upgrade path is required for that installation and proceed with the update as needed.